# How do I explore the results of an ActiveRecord relation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

This is what I am doing:

```
[72] pry(main)> Connection.joins(:inviter_memberships).where(inviter_memberships: { invited: c.inviter_membership.invited })
=> #<Connection::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x3fe19aa2ce28>
```

But not sure how to explore that to see what records apply to that relation.

I have a `Connection` model, that has the following associations:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: connections
#
#  id                    :integer          not null, primary key
#  membership_id         :integer
#  invited_membership_id :integer
# truncated for brevity

class Connection < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :inviter_membership, class_name: "Membership", foreign_key: "membership_id"
  belongs_to :invited_membership, class_name: "Membership", foreign_key: "invited_membership_id"    
end
```

And I have a `Membership` model that looks like this:

```
class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :inviter, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "user_id"
  belongs_to :invited, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "invited_id"
  has_many :connections, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Comment: Add `.all` to the end.

Comment: 0
down vote
I am pretty sure this result (`=> #<Connection::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x3fe19aa2ce28>`) means your query is wrong and calling `.all`, `.first`, `.last` or any other method on the collection will undisguise the error you have in SQL.

Comment: i think try `.as_json` filter will explore query result details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#<Connection::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x3fe19aa2ce28>` means your query has something wrong, more info [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html)

Regarding explore the results of your query:
Well there are 2 ways in which you can take a look, the easier is to add `.all` at the end of your query, and the other is to do the following in your prompt

```
Connection.joins(:inviter_memberships).where(inviter_memberships: { invited: c.inviter_membership.invited }).each do |record|
  puts "---------"
  puts record
end
```

Using `first`, `second`, `third`, `last` will show you the the query you are applying then you can take a look and debug what's wrong with your query